# html inputs within the label or outside?

Tags: css, checkbox, label

This site:
http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <div class="onoffswitch-inner"></div>
    <div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

The issue with this is the labels seem to require the use of the for attribute and the checkboxes require an id. Obviously with a form of many checkboxes this could prove quite annoying to have to create unqiue id's all the time. I altered it slightly (the css is on the fiddle), but does anyone know if there is a reason the checkbox was originally placed outside the label and not within? It seems to work fine within..

http://jsfiddle.net/UJw4F/

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <label class="onoffswitch-label">
     <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" checked="checked"/>
    <div class="onoffswitch-inner"></div>
    <div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

This other guy has done the same with placing the checkbox outside the label:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/radio-buttons-clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

w3.org - Any input element descendant of a label element with a for attribute must have an ID value that matches that for attribute

Without the 'for' attribute

You can do

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" checked="checked"/>
<label class="onoffswitch-label">My Label</label>
```

And the label will be associated with the checkbox

Follow me #mickjguy

Comment: Yes as I stated in my post. However, why? It seems to work fine without with the added benefit that the label and input do not require a for and id attribute which lessens the html your app musr produce and lessens the logic as the app doesn't need to calculate unique id's for them. If the only reason is for w3.org but it works everywhere then i see no point.

Comment: Hi John, the best reason is for accessibility. If you have ever tried a screen reader you will know how difficult it can be to navigate a page. I recommend you put your site/app through wave.webaim.org to get an idea of accessibility issues. It's a great resource.